# GLOBAL_PageId not work

Tags: bigcommerce

i'm trying display diffirent banner on diffirent home page by css

i use %%GLOBAL_PageId%% to display page id but it is not work no thing to display,

%%GLOBAL_PageId%% just work on contact page only

please help,

Answer (score 0):

I check for:
%%GLOBAL_PageNumber%% to check if it is a blog post
%%GLOBAL_PageTitle%% to check if this is a static page (like you mentioned contact page) 
%%GLOBAL_CatId%% to check if it is a category page

If none of the above are set, I assume it is a product page. But there are also login, wishlist and other predefined bigcommerce pages that I don't know how can be tracked.